# My recursive code that manipulates nested Objects and bulk inserts them into PSQL DB is slow. Is there a faster way?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, algorithm, recursion, typeorm

I have large dataset with the name of `Rows` in the format of an array containing multi-levels deep Objects, each row could have an array of `subrows`, each one has the same properties of the `parent` row. a dataset that If "flattened" into one level objects will result in up to 50-100 Million objects.

The Goal is to insert each item as an entry into a PostgresQl db entity, Notice that we need to take take into consideration that each time we insert a `subRow` it must have the `Id` of the `parentRow` as a property called `parentId`, the Id of each item is an automatically generated Integer. the parentId is an optional field because not all rows have parentRows but we must obtain and save the parentId when necessary in order to keep track of the initial Hierarchy.

Here is a data sample:

```js
{
  "modelId": 1,
  "subRows": [
    {
      "visualId": "01.01.10",
      "elementForgeDbIds":[222904, 222905 ,222906 ,222912, 222913],
      "description": "parent 1",
      "subRows": [
        {
          "visualId": "01.01.10",
          "elementForgeDbIds": [222923, 222926,222927 ,222931],
          "description": "child 1 of parent 1",
          "subRows": [
            {
              "visualId": "01.01.10",
              "elementForgeDbIds": [1, 2 ,3 ,4, 5, 6],
              "description": "child 1 of child 1",
              "classificationFormula": [],
              "subRows": [
                {
                  "visualId": "01.01.10",
                  "elementForgeDbIds": [1, 2 ,3 ,4, 5, 6],
                  "description": "terminal 1",
                  "classificationFormula": [],
                  "subRows": []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "visualId": "01.01.10",
              "elementForgeDbIds": [1, 2 ,3 ,4, 5, 6],
              "description": "child 2 of child 1",
              "classificationFormula": [],
              "subRows": [
                {
                  "visualId": "01.01.10",
                  "elementForgeDbIds": [1, 2 ,3 ,4, 5, 6],
                  "description": "terminal 2",
                  "classificationFormula": [],
                  "subRows": []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "visualId": "01.01.10",
              "elementForgeDbIds": [1, 2 ,3 ,4, 5, 6],
              "description": "child 3 of child 1",
              "classificationFormula": ["ID.02.10.0020"],
              "subRows": [
                {
                  "visualId": "01.01.10",
                  "elementForgeDbIds": [1, 2 ,3 ,4, 5, 6],
                  "description": "child 3 of child 2",
                  "classificationFormula": [],
                  "subRows": [
                    {
                      "visualId": "01.01.10",
                      "elementForgeDbIds": [1, 2 ,3 ,4, 5, 6],
                      "description": "child 4 of child 3",
                      "classificationFormula": [],
                      "subRows": [
                        {
                          "visualId": "01.01.10",
                          "elementForgeDbIds": [1, 2 ,3 ,4, 5, 6],
                          "description": "terminal 3",
                          "classificationFormula": [],
                          "subRows": []
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "visualId": "01.01.10",
      "elementForgeDbIds": [222923, 222926,222927 ,222931],
      "description": "parent 2",
      "classificationFormula": [],
      "subRows": [
        {
          "visualId": "01.01.10",
          "elementForgeDbIds": [222923, 222926,222927 ,222931],
          "description": "child 1 of parent 2",
          "classificationFormula": [],
          "subRows": [
            {
              "visualId": "01.01.10",
              "description": "terminal 4",
              "classificationFormula": [],
              "subRows": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "visualId": "01.01.10",
      "description": "parent 3",
      "elementForgeDbIds": [222923, 222926,222927 ,222931],
      "classificationFormula": [],
      "subRows": [
        {
          "visualId": "01.01.10",
          "description": "child 1 of parent 3",
          "elementForgeDbIds": [222923, 222926,222927 ,222931],
          "classificationFormula": [],
          "subRows": [
            {
              "visualId": "01.01.10",
              "description": "terminal 5",
              "elementForgeDbIds": [222923, 222926,222927 ,222931],
              "classificationFormula": ["ID.02.10.0020"],
              "subRows": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and here is my recursive solution to it. I left comments above each line to explain what I am trying to do:

```js
class RowService {

  private terminalRows: IRow[] = []
  private subRows: Partial<Row>[] = []
  private modelId: string

  constructor(private rowRepository: Repository<RowEntity>)
  
  
  async createRows(payload: CreateBoqRowDTO) {
      const { modelId, subRows: rows } = payload
      this.modelId = modelId
      /** handle parent rows */
      for (const row of rows) {
         const { subRows, parentId, classificationFormula, elementForgeDbIds } = row
         if (subRows && Array.isArray(subRows) && subRows.length) {
            /** set model Id of the current parent row */
            row.modelId = modelId
            /** save current Parent row to obtain its Id which will then be the parentId for its children */
            const { id: currentParentId } = await this.saveRow(row)
            this.insertedParentRow++

            /** push children of the current row into subRows class member */
            this.subRows.push(
               ...subRows.map((row) => {
                  row.parentId = currentParentId
                  return row
               }),
            )
         } else {
            /** handle (save) terminal elements */
            row.modelId = modelId
            row.parentId = parentId
            this.terminalRows.push(row)
            await this.saveRow(row)
            this.insertedTerminalRow++
         }
      }

      /** handle subRows */
      if (this.subRows.length) {
         /** extract the first row of subRows class member in order to exclude it from the next recursive iteration */
         const currentRow = this.subRows.shift()
         /** assemble the original method payload with the current row */
         const payload = {
            modelId: this.modelId,
            subRows: [currentRow],
         }

         /** Recursive call here */
         return await this.createRows(payload)
      }

      await this.rowRepo.save(this.terminalRows)
   }

   async saveRow(row): Promise<Row> {
      const { parentId, visualId, description, grouping, classificationFormula, modelId } = row
      const newRow: any = this.rowRepo.create({
         modelId,
         parentId,
         visualId,
         description,
         classificationFormula: { ...classificationFormula },
      })
      return await this.rowRepo.save(newRow)
   }

}
```

this actually works when it comes to keeping track of the hierarchy, But It is extremely slow. I would greatly appreciate if someone could suggest a better approach to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're saving each row on its own (with a separate database request). I don't know typeorm, but surely there's a way to save multiple rows at once?

Comment: there is indeed bulk insert and I use it to insert above in the last line of the `createRows()` method, but because we need to obtain the Id of the parent Object when it has children I need to insert them one by one, Do you see a better idea to achieve the same result which is maintaining the hierarchy but faster?

Comment: Oh, I missed that, I guess i was confused because even for the terminal rows for which you do `this.terminalRows.push(row)` to save them later, you *also* do `await this.saveRow(row)`. Drop that and you should already get a considerable speed-up :-)

Comment: If you save multiple rows at once, you still should be able to get back their ids (output in the same order as input), no reason to save parents individually.

Comment: actually dropping the `await this.saveRow(row)` in the `else {}` clause did help, it was unnecessary. with regards to bulk inserting parents, sure I may still get the Ids in the same order but then I still need to link each Id with each direct child before inserting the children. and Honestly I don't see how could that be achieved atm.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://typeorm.io/#/tree-entities already?

Comment: actually I didn't see this feature before and it looks very promising to my problem, I will investigate and try it. thanks a lot :)

Comment: I can write an answer later for how I would've done it manually, but if you can make tree entities work it's probably a lot easier

Comment: the main concern is the "read" performance given that I need to retrieve an average of 50,000 records from a table that contains over 100 million records. not only that, there is a many-to-many relation between the `row` entity in which I am inserting as shown above, and another entity called `element`, each "row" can "own" about 50 elements.
I still didn't try the tree feature by TypeORM, but yeah this is what I am basically trying to achieve.